# Installing PERCL GeoIP for PHP on windows XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, geoip

I'm currently working on an application that needs some [GeoIP functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php), I've gotten the extension from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/geoip/1.0.8/ however, i'm having some difficulties installing the extension on xampp for windows. Please i need help on this...

i know how to install it on other systems:

To install geoip on debian lenny:

```
wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat

sudo apt-get install php5-geoip
```

But i still dont know how to do in in windows XAMPP. PLEASE HELP.

Answer (score 7):

For PHP version 5.6 in xampp with windows 7,10
Create test.php inside your htdocs directory and type `echo phpinfo();` and run it in any browser

[image: Architecture of php]

Check Architecture column from above image
If it x86 then

1. download **geoip** extension from 
   http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/geoip/1.1.0/php_geoip-1.1.0-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip
2. Extract in your computer
3. Copy php_geoip.dll to C:\xampp\php\ext\
4. Add this line in the end of php.ini:- **extension=php_geoip.dll**
5. Restart Apache
6. Run test.php again which you have created above.
7. Now you can see geoip is enabled
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

1. Copy the relevant library [pecl.php.net/package/geoip/1.1.0/windows](http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip/1.1.0/windows)
2. Extract in your computer
3. Copy php_geoip.dll to C:\xampp\php\ext [Your xampp > php > ext folder (PHP 5)]
4. Add extension=php_geoip.dll in php.ini
5. Restart Apache
6. If you downloaded wrong DLL it will give you error message like: platform missmatch
7. go to phpinfo. find geoip

Answer (score 0):

## Install geoip on xampp

Geocoding (finding latitude/longitude for street addresses), Geotagging (tagging media with latitude/longitude coordinates), and Geolocation (finding latitude/longitude of computer with IP X-Forwarded-For). There are some options to install on linux environment:

```
# wget http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
# gunzip GeoLiteCity.dat.gz
# sudo mkdir -v /usr/share/GeoIP
# sudo mv -v GeoLiteCity.dat /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat
```

[image: geoIP-Dat-Files.png][source](http://blog.svnlabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/geoIP-Dat-Files.png)

## Installing GeoIP on XAMPP for windows

In Windows environment we have to add extension `php_geoip.dll` with PHP Download extension from here : `http://blog.svnlabs.com/php-5.2.1_geoip-w32.zip`

Copy `php_geoip.dll` to xampp `php/ext` .. add a line in php.ini
`extension=php_geoip.dll` and restart xampp

thats all :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the GeoIP for Xampp with the .HTACCESS method but i couldn't make it work with Rajesh solution so, this is what it worked for me:

1. Download the right VC version from [ApacheHouse](https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx) (you can check
   your compilation version and architecture with `echo phpinfo();`)
2. Follow the readme_first.html included in the downloaded ZIP file to
   install GeoIP*.

   - Copy the database to -> c:/xampp/apache/bin/geoip.dat
   - Copy the mod_geoip.so to -> c:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_geoips.so
   - Load the mod_geoip.so in httpd.conf -> LoadModule geoip_module modules/mod_geoip.so
   - Add in httpd.conf at the bottom:

     ```
     <IfModule geoip_module>
         GeoIPEnable On
         GeoIPDBFile bin/GeoIP.dat
     </IfModule>
     ```
   - Restart Apache service